# Como tratar exceções de duplicidade em constraint unique?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa

Fala devs, tudo bem?

Qual a melhor forma de lidar com erros de duplicidade quando tenta criar campo com constraint unique?

Apenas deixo a exceção acontecer? Ou eu um findByAlgumCampo e se já existir eu não faço o save(..) ?

Comment: sem mais informações do cenário fica difícil responder, vai ser "baseada em opiniões". Se isso for acontecer raramente, já que tem a constraint no banco, deixe dar erro, coloque o código num try/catch e pronto. Se acontecer com frequência pode fazer mais sentido validar antes. A melhor estratégia depende da query, se a tabela é pequena e pode usar cache, muitas variáveis. A princípio deixe dar erro, trate e use um log, dependendo dos resultados (muitos erros, etc) pode mudar no futuro

Comment: a ideia era deixar genérico porque eu queria saber se havia algum padrão a ser seguido.  porém, mais tarde, descobri que a exceção é mais genérica do que eu gostaria e exige a mesma quantidade de código (se não mais) para identificar que foi do tipo 'duplicidade'.

Comment: em geral os providers de acesso a banco de dados retornam erros mais específicos em casos de constraint, olhe bem isso. Validar antes também significa fazer duas operações ao no banco de dados, select e insert. Como eu comenti na pergunta, tem analisar bem o seu caso, mas o mais simples é deixar dar exception e tratar

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem e por ai?

Então, tudo depende da regra de negócio da sua aplicação. Mas eu acredito que se você fizer o `find` antes e não executar o `save(...)`, você terá que informar algum erro para o usuário dizendo que o dado não foi salvo por já existir.

Então nesse sentido, acredito que é melhor deixar a `exception` acontecer, mas tratá-la no momento de exibir para o usuário (ou retornar na API).

No caso da API, é importante que o erro de banco não seja retornado diretamente, mas que você trate ele, e retorne uma mensagem mais "genérica":

```js
{
    "erro": "O registro já existe"
}
```

Mas como falei ali, tudo depende da regra de negócio da aplicação, e do cenário em questão.

Algo assim.